# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a view that has context data and it extends base.html but as I want the context data to be displayed in all templates that extend from base.html and not only the view with the context data I am doing custom template tags with the context inside but I get an error.

view with and without context data:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name='products'
    template_name = 'main/home.html'
    paginate_by = 25


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name='products'
    template_name = 'main/home.html'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        news = News.objects.all()
        context.update({
            'categories' : categories,
            'news' : news,
        })
        
        return context
```

base.html with and without the custom tag

```
{% news %}


{% for new in news %}
    <p>{{ new.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The custom tag file templatetags/news.py

```
from django import template
from support.models import News


register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('news.html', takes_context=True)
def news(context):
    return {
        'news': News.objects.order_by("-date_posted")[0:25],
    }
```

The custom tag file templatetags/news.html

```
{% for new in news %}
    <p>{{ new.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

File structure:

Project

- main

  - templates/main

    - base.html
  - templatetags

    - news.py
    - news.html
  - models.py
  - urls.py
  - views.py
    ...
- project

  - settings.py
    ...

  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the python code containing your tag codes in the `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries':{
                'tagname': 'appname.news', # your template tag

            }
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: 'news': 'main.news', Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised...

Comment: can you share folder and file structure?

Comment: It's now on my post.

Comment: Write this in the library parameter `'news': 'templatetags.news'` , write this at the beginning of the html file `{%load news%}`

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing, you should `load` the template tag in news.html template which is registered.

Just load the tag in `news.html` template:

```
{% load tag_name %} #Add here tag name to load
```

Note: Please ensure that template tag setting is added in settings.py file